# Remove active class from bootstrap tabs from component in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-tabs

This is my products dashboard.html

```
   <nav #nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-categories-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-categories" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-categories" aria-selected="true" (click)="showCategories()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='categories'}">Categories</button>     
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-product-lists-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-product-lists" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-product-lists" aria-selected="false"(click)="showProducts()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='products'}">Products</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-product-details-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-product-details" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-product-details" aria-selected="false" (click)="showProductDetails()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='product-details'}">Product Details</button>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

This is my products dashboard component

```
    export class ProductsDashboardComponent {
    activeTab = 'categories';
    constructor(private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}
    showCategories(){
      this.router.navigate(['categories'],{relativeTo: this.route})
    }
    showProducts(){
      this.router.navigate(['products'],{relativeTo: this.route})
    }
    showProductDetails(){
      this.activeTab = 'product-details';
      this.router.navigate(['product-details'],{relativeTo: this.route})
    }
  }
```

Now when I click product details tab the previous tab which is products tab also shown as active as shown below. So, how do I make the other tabs class inactive.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to sync the active child, this will even work when we refresh the screen, we can subscribe to router events preferably `NavigationEnd` and then get the current `firstChild` path. Also the fix to your problem might be removing the active class from the html

full code

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  provideRouter,
  Router,
  RouterModule,
  NavigationEnd,
} from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'zone.js';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './categories/categories.component';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <nav #nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-categories-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-categories" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-categories" aria-selected="true" (click)="showCategories()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='categories'}">Categories</button>     
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-product-lists-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-product-lists" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-product-lists" aria-selected="false" (click)="showProducts()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='products'}">Products</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-product-details-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-product-details" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-product-details" aria-selected="false" (click)="showProductDetails()" [ngClass]="{ 'active':activeTab==='product-details'}">Product Details</button>
     </div>
     <router-outlet/>
  </nav>
  `,
})
export class App {
  activeTab = 'categories';
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.activeTab = this.route?.snapshot?.firstChild?.routeConfig?.path.split("/")[0] || '';
    })
  }
  showCategories() {
    this.router.navigate(['categories'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
  showProducts() {
    this.router.navigate(['products'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
  showProductDetails() {
    this.router.navigate(['product-details'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      { path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent },
      { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
      { path: 'product-details', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'categories', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3txyfw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fcategories%2Fcategories.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fproducts%2Fproducts.component.ts,src%2Fproduct-details%2Fproduct-details.component.ts,node_modules%2F%40angular%2Frouter%2Findex.d.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: @Naren-Thanks for pointing to the right direction but one issue I'm having when I'm trying to get this on the child component suppose If I have one button in the products tab and If I clicked it then it should go to product-details so here I need to track and make the tab active.

Comment: @coder please check my stackblitz even this scenario works!

Comment: @Narem-Yes I have gone through it but still its not showing the tab active. Can you please check my updated code

Comment: @coder Could you try `.path.split("/")[0]` to take only the first path segment?

Comment: @coder THe original question and the updated one seem to vary very largely, it should be a new question!

Comment: Ok I will add a new question..Thanks

Comment: Or you could just subscribe to `activatedRoute.queryParams`?